# Vaadin making table component dynamic or changing to grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

[Image : table changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Zrd.png)

So... I'm new to vaadin and java web development, and I'm having troubles to how to make this change, it easy to add a new column to the table component, but I need to make this dynamic so when a click a button like the image (number 6 sign) adds a new column with combobox data to be selected and also showing another button to continue adding more combobox...

Is it viable to make this with a table component and how it could be done, or is it easier to make this on a grid component.

The Grid Component gives me this info https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-grid.html that shows me all the functionality but it's still a traditional table style way.

Right now I'm loading the data as this:

```
for(int i=0; i<dataSourcesIdsToAdd.size(); i++)
    {
        Object[] rptKeyColMapItemValues = new Object[4];

        //Loading field types               
        ComboBox cbxDataSource = new ComboBox("");
        cbxDataSource.setStyleName("tiny");
        cbxDataSource.setRequired(true);
        cbxDataSource.setRequiredError("This field is required.");
        cbxDataSource.setHeight(20, Unit.PIXELS);
        cbxDataSource.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);   
        cbxDataSource.addItem(dataSourcesIdsToAdd.get(i));
        cbxDataSource.setItemCaption(dataSourcesIdsToAdd.get(i), dataSourcesNamesToAdd.get(i));
        cbxDataSource.setValue(dataSourcesIdsToAdd.get(i));
        cbxDataSource.setReadOnly(true);
        rptKeyColMapItemValues[0] = cbxDataSource;

        CheckBox chxMandatory = new CheckBox();
        chxMandatory.setStyleName("tiny");
        chxMandatory.setVisible(true);
        chxMandatory.setHeight(20, Unit.PIXELS);
        rptKeyColMapItemValues[1] = chxMandatory;

        ComboBox cbxDataSourceField = new ComboBox("");
        cbxDataSourceField.setStyleName("tiny");
        cbxDataSourceField.setRequired(true);
        cbxDataSourceField.setRequiredError("This field is required.");
        cbxDataSourceField.setHeight(20, Unit.PIXELS);
        cbxDataSourceField.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        rptKeyColMapItemValues[2] = cbxDataSourceField;

        Button btnNewColumn = new Button(FontAwesome.PLUS_CIRCLE);
        btnNewColumn.setHeight(20, Unit.PIXELS);
        rptKeyColMapItemValues[3] = btnNewColumn;

        tblKeyColumnMapping.addItem(rptKeyColMapItemValues, dataSourcesIdsToAdd.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it maybe be easier to create a custom composition component for the part with a dashed outline, instead of trying to fit Table or Grid to this dynamic, ever-growing format? It could be something like

```
public class DataSourceComponent extends HorizontalLayout {
  private ComboBox dataSourceTable;
  private CheckBox mandatory;
  private List<DataSourceFieldComponent> fields;

  ...

  public void setDataSource(DataSourceObject ds) { ... }
```

Each of these DataSourceFieldComponent would be similarily a composite of the ComboBox and add button. (alternatively the upper component takes care of adding a ComboBox and Button in as a pair.) Put a defined width on each component and they will align nicely. I guess you would have to modify this idea a little as the fields come in pair, but I guess you get the idea.

Then one level above you would have a view that renders the header and takes in a list of these data source objects , and initializes a DataSourceComponent for each.

Comment: so that DataSourceComponent would be inside of a table/grid ? or is going to be all rows of my new custom component with datasource in it.

Comment: I would put those components into a VerticalLayout which takes in a list of these DataSource data objects and generates one component per each. No Table/Grid anywhere.

Comment: You could of course still keep Table and try to add manual columns for each additional plus press, "datasourceid1", "datasourceid2" etc. I just don't see that much benefit out of using a table when you don't have a strictly tabular format and you don't seem to need lazy loading when there doesn't seem to be hundreds of rows.